# How to use SQL column name only if the column exists?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've been trying to get a textual result from `CASE(def.OPTION_CATEGORY_ID)`  in a select, but I'm having a hard time implementing the terms.

What I'm trying to do is to check if `OPTION_CATEGORY_ID` is an existing column in sys.columns. If it is then I'm trying to make the int to text translation using the `When - Then` on the bottom but the SQL is not aware of the column name so `CASE(def.OPTION_CATEGORY_ID)` is failing because the column name is invalid.

Is there any way to call `def.OPTION_CATEGORY_ID` using an alias name so the SQL won't fail it before hand?
  Thanks

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
    FROM
      (SELECT def.OPTION_DEF_ID AS 'Def ID',
              ass.ASSET_NAME AS 'Asset Name',
              CASE(def.OPTION_TYPE_ID)
                  WHEN 1 THEN 'A'
                  WHEN 2 THEN 'B'

              END AS 'Option Type',
              case when exists (SELECT name
              FROM   sys.columns 
              WHERE  Name  = 'OPTION_CATEGORY_ID'
                     AND Object_ID = Object_ID(N'TFC_OPTION_DEFINITION')) 

    then
        -- Column Exists
         CASE(def.OPTION_CATEGORY_ID) 
                  WHEN 1 THEN 'C'
                  WHEN 2 THEN 'D'
                  WHEN 3 THEN 'E'
                  WHEN 4 THEN 'F'


              end
              End AS 'test' ,

        -- the rest of the select
```

Comment: You're trying to do too much at once.  This kind of "SQL-in-SQL" doesn't work.  What you need to do is query the schema and generate a single string variable that holds a new SQL statement *(SQL that writes SQL)*.  Then, as a separate step, you can run that string as a SQL Statement using `EXEC sp_executesql`, which also supports parameterised queries.  Google `Dynamic-SQL and SQL-Server` for more details.

Comment: what's the goal behind this requirement? maybe there is an easier way to get there...

Comment: My DB might and might not have the column "OPTION_CATEGORY_ID" inside def.
I want to use the same Query in both cases but when it exists i want the bottom case to generate the correct text translation for the int ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to select a column and you are not sure if it exists, you cannot write it explicitly in your code, and expect it to compile.

You should build the statement dynamically based on the **run time** information of which the column exists or not:

```
DECLARE @statement VARCHAR(MAX)

IF((SELECT COUNT(*)
              FROM   sys.columns 
              WHERE  Name  = 'OPTION_CATEGORY_ID'
                     AND Object_ID = Object_ID(N'TFC_OPTION_DEFINITION')) > 0)
BEGIN
 SET @statement = --assign a query which uses OPTION_CATEGORY_ID
END
ELSE
BEGIN
 SET @statement = --assign a query which does not use OPTION_CATEGORY_ID
END

EXEC sp_executesql @statement
```